# Why is collectstatic only detecting admin static files?

Tags: django, python-django-storages

I'm using S3 to store my static files, but I'm having an issue where only the admin static files are uploading to the bucket.

I expected to see the css and other folders from inside static upload to the bucket, but instead, this is all I got:

```
static/
- admin/
- flags/
```

What can I do to get my app's static folder to upload also?

Looking at other answers to this question, it seems like the main difference is that my project uses django-sass-processor, but I'm not sure why that would mean my entire folder is not picked up.

Project folder structure:

```
backend/
- accounts/
- core/
-- settings.py
-- ...
- static/
- templates/
```

settings.py

```
USE_S3 = os.getenv('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]

SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: I think you may be missing `'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder'` in `STATICFILES_FINDERS`.

Comment: Adding this gives the error 'The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting'